# Can you electrically polarize gas?

Tags: electricity, electric-fields, polarization, gas, molecules

If you put a non-polar gas like $\rm CO_2$ in a positive electric field, Will it get polarized? What will be the force the molecules get as its attracted to the positive field?

Answer (score 1):

CO$_2$ is a molecule with structure $C{\bf =}O{\bf =}C$ so that it's linear. In each single $C{\bf =}O$ the oxygen atom is more electronegative than the carbon atom.

That is, there are two individual dipoles that point outward from the carbon atom to the oxygen atom. But because the dipoles have equal strength, and point in opposite directions (linear molecule), the dipole moments cancel out so that the overall polarity of the CO$_2$ molecule is zero.

Because it has no polarity, it will not tend to align with a uniform electric field (provided it is not very large, say up to $5-10Vm^{-1}$) when placed in one. Only polar molecules will do this.

But for larger electric fields, this may not be the case, and the result is that the molecules may experience a force.

Comment: CO2 has no polarity, but it polarizes in electric field and will move in nonuniform electric field.

Comment: We must be talking about a very large electric field. And I don’t think that paper you cited speaks of standard polarisation  in context of the OP’s question.

Comment: Very large compared to what? The paper is about "polarizability". And why is the paper not relevant?

Comment: Have you seen how small the value of polarizability is? Of the order $10^{-41}$. That is laughably small, and in a standard uniform electric field, such polarization is not even detectable. BTW I have not read the paper yet.

Comment: This value is per one molecule, Coulomb is a huge charge, and polarizability of CO2 is quite detectable, as evidenced by the refraction index of 1.00045 at normal conditions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_refractive_indices). So the expression "laughably small" may be too strong.

Comment: Yes, and the OP is asking about putting CO_2 molecules in an electric field. For an electric field that is large enough, anything will polarize - so then what would be the point of OPs question? CO_2 is non-polar and because it has no moment, in a standard uniform E-field there will be no (or very little) polarization.

Comment: The OP is not asking about putting "molecules" in an electric field, he is asking about putting a "gas" in an electric field, i.e. a "lot" of molecules. "No polarization" in electric field is definitely wrong (it does not matter if the field is uniform or not, this only matters for the total force acting on molecules) and "very little" does not make sense in physics unless it is "very little compared to something else".

Comment: If you have not read the paper, then what you "don't think" about it is probably not relevant?

Comment: Yeah you might be right. I'll have a read of it ASAP and get back to you here. Thanks. PS when I say very little I mean an electric field of a few volts/meter.

Comment: So the dielectric constant of CO2 at normal conditions is approximately 1.001 (https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/relative-permittivity-d_1660.html), so such gas changes the electric field by one thousandth. Not much, but not negligible.

Comment: Thanks. It is not much but noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

Isotropic polarizability of CO2 is, roughly, 15 atomic units ([J. Phys. Chem. A 2000, 104, 11355-11361](https://faculty.missouri.edu/%7Eglaserr/vitpub/jp002927r.pdf)), and atomic unit of dipole polarizability is $1.64877727436 \times 10^{-41} C^2 m^2 J^{-1}$. [The force acting on a dipole in non-uniform electric field](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Electricity_and_Magnetism/Book%3A_Electricity_and_Magnetism_(Tatum)/03%3A_Dipole_and_Quadrupole_Moments/3.05%3A_Force_on_a_Dipole_in_an_Inhomogeneous_Electric_Field)

Comment: @akhmetali: thank you for your help, this clarifies many questions I had earlier!